# Putty Plink to download remote file not working

Tags: unix, putty, plink

I am trying the **putty** **plink** and **pscp** commands from a windows batch file to download file from Linux server.

For server#1, these commands works fine when the remote server has SFTP enabled(port will be 22 in the given command). For server#2, which has only FTP enabled, plink is not working.

Server #1(SFTP) => `plink 10.238.xxx.xxx -P 22 -l "uname" -pw "pass123" -- This works`

Server #2(FTP) => Tried below 2 commands, but no luck

`plink uname@10.238.xxx.xxx -P 21 -pw "pass123" -- This does not work`

`plink 10.238.xxx.xxx -P 21 -l "uname" -pw "pass123" -- This does not work`

To make sure only FTP works on Server #2, tried connecting on WinSCP and could see that SFTP does not work and I am able to connect and download when the file protocol selected is FTP. When selecting SFTP, getting the error - "You are trying to access a restricted zone. Only Authorized Users allowed." which is expected in my case.

Please share your views on how to use plink & pscp to download files over FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plink do not operate FTP protocol. If you want to use FTP you have to use proper client (windows have build-in client try command `ftp /?`. If you server support SCP protocol to file transfer, you could use pscp.exe (plinks brother).

Comment: That. And also, plink cannot be used to download *anything*. It's not a file transfer tool.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - I am using plink for executing ssh commands where as pscp is used for download/copy files between a remote server and a windows machine

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you trying to use `plink` to execute `pscp` on a remote machine to transfer file to/from yet another remote machine?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl For me, both `plink` and `pscp` are not working. The server has only FTP enabled. Could you please suggest an alternative approach in this case ?

Comment: You already got a suggestion from @user2956477 – Use FTP client. You cannot use `plink`/`pscp` with FTP server.